# Removing trailing white spaces after text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that I have a file with several SQL queries, all separated by ";". If put the contents of the file in a string and do:

```
with open(query_file) as f:
    query = f.read()
    f.close()

queries = query.split(';')
```

I'll get a list where each item is one of the queries. Which is my final objective. However, how do I include here that if the last item is only spaces, next lines, tabs or an empty string to remove it? Can it be done via the .split()? I want to avoid things like this:

```
>>> a = 'a;b;'
>>> a.split(';')
['a', 'b', '']
```

Or this (this is a bad example, but you get the idea):

```
>>> a = '''a;b;\n'''
>>> a.split(';')
['a', 'b', '\n']
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm open to other approaches as well, basically separating the string into all the individual queries.

Comment: This is a problematic approach, since the semicolon can be part of a string, like `SELECT a FROM b WHERE c == ';';`. You need a parser to obtain the commands, not split on a character.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're totally right, just edited the question. I'm open to other approaches

Comment: Can you re-write the file to use a different delimiter? Like `-- Next query\n`?

Comment: Is your delimiter just a semicolon, or is it actually a semicolon followed by a newline (maybe with optional other whitespace beforehand)? In other words, can you ever have two queries on a single line? (Your last example clearly _does_ have two queries on the same line, but does that ever actually happen in your real file?)

Comment: Anyway, there are dozens of SQL parsing libraries out there (although picking one that's actually correct can be hard from among the toy versions that work 98% of the time but are fundamentally flawed and can't be fixed for the other 2%). That's the obvious right solution here if you need to parse a sequence of arbitrary SQL statements with semicolon terminators.